# Multiple inputs on logstash jdbc for mysql cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

For example, I have 8 dbs, like `db0`, `db1`, `db2`, ... , `db7`.
And in each db, I have nearly 1024 tables sharing with the same structure, and the tables' name are `table0001`, `table0002`, `table0003`,..., `table1024`.
As far as I can know, for each db and table, there must has a `jdbc` config corresponding to it. For example,

```
input {
      jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db0"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from table0001"
        type => "table0001"
      }
      jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db0"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from table0002"
        type => "table0002"
      }
      ...
      jdbc {
        jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db0"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "password"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from table1024"
        type => "table1024"
      }

    }
```

There are so many redundant configs, such as `jdbc_driver_library`, `jdbc_driver_class` and so on.

Is there any mechanism like wildcard to avoid redundant configs? Especially when using in splitting table situation.

Comment: So we're talking 8K+ tables to pull from every minute?

Comment: Yes, I've met this requirement.

Comment: And how many records are we talking?

Comment: Not pretty sure, but I guess there will be not too much records in each table.  Besides, I'm wondering that logstash will suit this situation.

Comment: Having 8K inputs being polled every minute is not the best design for a single Logstash. You can certainly parallelize your inputs on different Logstash instances though

Comment: I have considered the way you mentioned above. But in every single Logstash instances, it still has redundant configs when splitting table as I  wrote above.

Comment: It's easy to generate all those configs in one shot (via shell, etc), I'm more concerned about the load than the config.